# What is the opposite of "crowded" ("uncrowded" is simply "not full of people" not "very few people")?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

> [crowded](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/crowded?q=crowded): having a lot of people or too many people
>
> We made our way through the crowded streets.
>
> a crowded bar
>
> The main beach can get really crowded in summer.
>
> London was very crowded.
>
> crowded with somebody In the spring the place is crowded with skiers.

---

> [uncrowded](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/uncrowded?q=uncrowded): not full of people
>
> The beach was pleasantly uncrowded.

---

I don't think "**uncrowded**" is a complete opposite of "**crowded**". "**Uncrowded**" is simply "**not full of people**", it does not mean "**very few people**".

The opposite of "**crowded**" is "**very few people**"

What is the opposite of "**crowded**" ?

Answer (score 2):

While I might opine that "uncrowded" is indeed the opposite of "crowded," much like "unintelligent" is the opposite of "intelligent," you explain your position well and I do understand your question.

The thesaurus gives these antonyms: deserted, empty, imprecise, loose, uncongested, unfilled, and, yes, uncrowded.

Looking at the synonyms for deserted, I find barren, derelict, desolate, empty, forlorn, isolated, lonely, neglected, uninhabited and vacant.

You may wish to wander around in the thesaurus and dictionary to find a word that feels appropriate in the context in which you're using it. I use [this one](https://thesaurus.com).

Comment: "Almost deserted" seems like a good choice for the opposite sought. Another possibility is "sparsely peopled", although that sounds like the description of a territory.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Yeah, you could bite the bullet and use two words. I thought of variations of "sparse" as well, with much the same feeling as yours.

Comment: I would call an island 'desolate' if it not only had few people, but also all buildings wrecked, trees uprooted, etc, by a natural disaster.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, so would I.

Answer (score 1):

This is very much a matter of style and intention. If I were describing Times Square in its current state, I would say it is *desolate*.

Comment: If discussing a normally crowded place or e.g. town, you could say it was deserted.

Comment: That's not what 'desolate' means.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey *desolate* is listed as a synonym of *deserted* in the thesaurus. Both can mean deserted (desolation being potentially an effect of desertion), although the former carries a further connotation of sadness.

Comment: If somewhere is desolate it has nothing, not just no people.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That is one definition. There are others, including "deprived or destitute of inhabitants; deserted; uninhabited." Kind of like, you know, Times Square in its current state. (See https://www.dictionary.com/browse/desolate.)